# How to get dependencies size with gradle task in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I need to create a task that displays each dependency size when executed.

I've searched for a way to do it and the closest answer is [this](https://gist.github.com/medvedev/968119d7786966d9ed4442ae17aca279) however, this solution seems to work for non Android projects only.

I'm currently using the **tools.build:gradle:3.4.2** and the **gradle plugin for android 5.1.1**

I would like something to list each dependency and size like:

```
- Retrofit 2.5.0 ------ 654 KB.

- Butterknife 10.1.0 -- 150 KB.
```

I tried to implement the gist I linked before but it always says:

> ERROR: Cannot change strategy of configuration ':app:androidApis' after it has been resolved.

After removing a piece of the code for multiple configurations:

> ERROR: Cannot change strategy of configuration ':app:default' after it has been resolved.

At this point I don't know what to put at configuration...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to put the script mentioned [here](https://gist.github.com/medvedev/968119d7786966d9ed4442ae17aca279) inside `project.afterEvaluate{}`, e.g.

```
project.afterEvaluate {
    tasks.create("depsize") {
        listConfigurationDependencies(configurations.default)
    }

    tasks.create("depsize-all-configurations") {
        configurations.each {
            if (it.isCanBeResolved()) {
                listConfigurationDependencies(it)
            }
        }
    }

}

def listConfigurationDependencies(Configuration configuration) {
    def formatStr = "%,10.2f"

    def size = configuration.collect { it.length() / (1024 * 1024) }.sum()

    def out = new StringBuffer()
    out << "\nConfiguration name: \"${configuration.name}\"\n"
    if (size) {
        out << 'Total dependencies size:'.padRight(65)
        out << "${String.format(formatStr, size)} Mb\n\n"

        configuration.sort { -it.length() }
                .each {
            out << "${it.name}".padRight(65)
            out << "${String.format(formatStr, (it.length() / 1024))} kb\n"
        }
    } else {
        out << 'No dependencies found';
    }
    println(out)
}
```

Then run below command you will get the size printed.

```sh
$ ./gradlew depsize
```

For example, my output is as following:

```
Configuration name: "minApi16ReleaseRuntimeClasspath"
Total dependencies size:                                               2.90 Mb

appcompat-v7-26.1.0.aar                                              980.85 kb
support-compat-26.1.0.aar                                            621.42 kb
recyclerview-v7-26.1.0.aar                                           335.80 kb
support-media-compat-26.1.0.aar                                      304.53 kb
support-core-ui-26.1.0.aar                                           227.63 kb
support-fragment-26.1.0.aar                                          160.75 kb
constraint-layout-solver-1.0.2.jar                                    93.32 kb
support-core-utils-26.1.0.aar                                         85.11 kb
constraint-layout-1.0.2.aar                                           37.28 kb
animated-vector-drawable-26.1.0.aar                                   34.33 kb
support-vector-drawable-26.1.0.aar                                    30.74 kb
support-annotations-26.1.0.jar                                        24.13 kb
common-1.0.0.jar                                                      12.08 kb
common-1.0.0.jar                                                      10.89 kb
runtime-1.0.0.aar                                                      9.38 kb
support-v4-26.1.0.aar                                                  3.01 kb
```

See: https://gist.github.com/medvedev/968119d7786966d9ed4442ae17aca279#gistcomment-3003945

Comment: Thank you, this solves my problem, I've accepted your answer as the solution.

Comment: I'm getting this error on a React Native project with 'react-native-webview' installed:
`Could not create task ':app:depsize-all-configurations'.
   > Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugAndroidTestCompileClasspath'.
      > More than one variant of project :react-native-webview matches the consumer attributes:` - any ideas?

Comment: Does not work for me. Working on gradle version 7.0.2

Comment: @MarvinEffing, give the following response on a similar stack overflow question a try. https://stackoverflow.com/a/38054462/1910527
I was personally able to get it working without changing it on Gradle version `7.6.1`.

Answer (score 2):

**[This site is no longer active]** I have launched a new website to just do this. I am hoping to build an index for all libraries. The first time the lookup is going to be slow but subsequent lookups will be faster. Please check out the website at [droidanalyser.tools](http://droidanalyser.tools/?utm_source=stackoverflow&utm_medium=answer&utm_campaign=stackoverflow)

Comment: Works great for most packages, but the second attribute doesn't work fort this one :

com.huawei.hms:health:5.1.0.302
maven {url 'https://developer.huawei.com/repo/'}

Comment: There is a bug in the url encoding which is causing this error. Will fix it soon. Thanks

Comment: Thanks Jude, does your result count also the sub dependencies size ?

Comment: The website is not opening