# How to know specific size added by each dependency in an Android APK?

Tags: android, android-studio

**Hi guys!**

Well, this is my problem. I have an APK which uses a lot of external SDK. But, the size has increased a lot in recent months. I'm looking for a strategy to find the specific size added by each external SDK or library.

I already tried APK analyzer, but it doesn't give that information. For now, I'm thinking of a Gradle script, but I want to know if another strategy exists.

In the end want I want to see is something like:

"code inside glide package is adding 2MB of size to final SDK"

Comment: Have you seen: [How to calculate the size of libraries that is added as a dependency in the Android project](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36897343/295004)

Comment: Yeah, I already check that, but It's the total size. It is not exactly what I need.